# Why this factorial function gives wrong result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def Factorial(n):
   result = 1
   for i in range(1,n):
        result = result * (result+1)
   print(result)
Factorial(5)
```

Results for first 5 numbers are:

1 -> 1

2 -> 2

3 -> 6

4 -> 42

5 -> 1806

What is incorrect in my function?

Comment: `result = result * (i + 1)`

Comment: @NickA I posted my answer before loading your comment, I deleted it now, sorry if it looked like I stole your thought! =)

Comment: @Vinicius no need to apologize, I would assume a lot of people saw the problem quite quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def Factorial(n):
   result = 1
   for i in range(1,n):
        result = result * (i+1)
   print(result)
```

Replace

```
result = result * (result+1)
```

with

```
result = result * (i + 1)
```